# Why checkboxes of symfony form looks weird?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I am using twig with standalone symfony form with bootstrap. Here is my template source code:

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
         {{ form_row(form.firstnameFa) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          {{ form_row(form.lastnameFa) }}
        </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col">
         {{ form_row(form.firstnameEn) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          {{ form_row(form.lastnameEn) }}
        </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col">
          {{ form_row(form.email) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
         {{ form_row(form.password) }}
        </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col">
          {{ form_row(form.birthDate) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
        </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col">
          {{ form_row(form.showPhoto) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
        </div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
        <div class="col">
          {{ form_row(form.applyCard) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col">
        </div>
      </div>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

And here is the html sorce I view:

```
<form name="form" method="post">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">
     <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 required" for="form_firstnameFa">نام</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" id="form_firstnameFa" name="form[firstnameFa]" required="required" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 required" for="form_lastnameFa">نام خانوادگی</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" id="form_lastnameFa" name="form[lastnameFa]" required="required" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="w-100"></div>

    <div class="col">
     <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 required" for="form_firstnameEn">نام به انگلیسی</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" id="form_firstnameEn" name="form[firstnameEn]" required="required" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 required" for="form_lastnameEn">نام خانوادگی به انگلیسی</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" id="form_lastnameEn" name="form[lastnameEn]" required="required" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="w-100"></div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 required" for="form_email">ایمل</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input type="email" id="form_email" name="form[email]" required="required" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
     <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 required" for="form_password">رمز عبور</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input type="password" id="form_password" name="form[password]" required="required" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>

<div class="w-100"></div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 required" for="form_birthDate">تاریخ تولد</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" id="form_birthDate" name="form[birthDate]" required="required" class="form-control" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>

<div class="w-100"></div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group row"><div class="col-sm-2"></div><div class="col-sm-10"><div class="form-check">        <input type="checkbox" id="form_showPhoto" name="form[showPhoto]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="1" />
        <label class="form-check-label required" for="form_showPhoto">درخواست صدور کارت دارید؟</label></div></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>

<div class="w-100"></div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group row"><div class="col-sm-2"></div><div class="col-sm-10"><div class="form-check">        <input type="checkbox" id="form_applyCard" name="form[applyCard]" required="required" class="form-check-input" value="1" />
        <label class="form-check-label required" for="form_applyCard">عکس شما در فهرست اعضا نشان داده شود؟</label></div></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>

  </div>

 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>

<input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="qwfZkACcKM9ylhGXAYoor8oV1DBNCMAE8nzPC8J_J24" /></form>
```

And here is the screenshot how it looks like [image]

1) Why checkboxes looks weird? They are on first letter of writting. How to fix it? This is the same with English.

2) And how to place the button in center there are two columns but the button must be in center?

EDIT: I just use bootstrap css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try styling your check-boxes with float right or margins, here are some examples:

```
.form-check input {
margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Or this:

```
.form-check input {
float:right;
}
```

EDIT: You can also try this:

```
.form-check-input {
    margin-right: -1.55rem;
}
```

Comment: Any chance you send us the CSS as well?

Comment: I edited the post and added the css. That's the only css I use.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue. Here is what I see: https://codepen.io/MistaPrime/pen/RwwPrRj
Can you create a codepen which can replicate that?
Is it because your browser is set to RTL by default?

Comment: Yes. This is rtl. How to fix if this is rtl?

Comment: How is your RTL triggered? Is it because of your CSS or because of your browser?

Comment: In .body method of css, I set it rtl. Not by browser. This is standard Chrome.

Comment: I'm not able to re-create that CSS. You can perhaps make a codepen and ensure the layout is identical so that we can troubleshoot.

Comment: Many thanks for trying to help. Here is codepen link https://codepen.io/joehark/pen/RwwPQYz

Comment: I edited my answer and added a `margin-right` style. Try that and let me know.

Comment: I tried. Nothing changed yet. I added your code to codepen that you see nothing changed. @MistaPrime

Comment: This is what it looks without my CSS: http://screenshot.how/UcWWSN     AND this is with my CSS: http://screenshot.how/AJkgmT      Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes. so why this is not applied on page with your css? you can verify this as I added your css to codepen. Also a bit alignment please as per this screenshot: https://imgur.com/NuORqgO plz look further. Let's start a chat?

Comment: And how to align center the button? @MistaPrime

Comment: It's working on codePen, with the link you shared, see screenshot: http://screenshot.how/glWfv9

Comment: To align center the button you would use this CSS: `.form-check {text-align: center;}` , it will look like this: http://screenshot.how/6466wR

Comment: I added form-check css above to codepen. Nothing changed. Plz see the codepen again. @MistaPrime

Comment: What do you mean **nothing changed** ? I see everything changed on **your** codepen link: http://screenshot.how/pYA4xb

Comment: Sorry. I was talking about submit button moving to center.  I said this is not aligned to center. @MistaPrime

Comment: To center the button add this CSS: `form button.btn.btn-primary {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}`
If that helps please click the checkmark on my answer and upvote it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all kind helps. But is it possible to align checkboxes under each other from right to left as I showed in screenshot above with a green line? @MistaPrime

Comment: Change the word `center` to the word `right` in the `.form-check {text-align: center;}` CSS.

Comment: Also my footer for short pages are not at the bottom, they are in middle of screen. I used fixed-bottom but with this, for long pages, this is over the last line of text and this is unreadable. How to fix that? @MistaPrime

Comment: For your footer issue please open a new request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200613/discussion-between-user4271704-and-mistaprime).